# Why do my banner and navbar have slightly different lengths when I set them to both width:100%?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a personal project that I am having a blast with when I noticed that my bootstrap 4 navbar and my banner have slightly different lengths, and that there is a slight horizontal scroll. I am not sure of the reason why, because my banner has hidden overflow, and I should have used % for any width related properties. I don't think there is anything that exceeds the width of the page either. At first I thought it was because of how I put the left padding of my top_header class to 20px, but when I attempted to change it to a % value, it did not work. Then I tried deleting it, and the problem persisted. Could someone please help me solve the problem?

Here is my HTML/CSS:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
  src: url("Montserrat-Regular.ttf");
}

#my_banner {
  background-image: url('banner.jpg');
  "
 padding-bottom: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#banner_chibi {
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar,
.dropdown-menu {
  background: #e5e5e5 !important;
  border: 0;
}

.navbar li a {
  color: #7e7e7e;
}

#top_header {
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#red {
  color: #cd2d3a;
}

#blue {
  color: #0047a0;
}

#main_content {
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.left_card {
  width: 20%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  position: fixed;
}

.right_card {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

#card_1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000%;
  top: 20%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #5e5e5e;
  overflow-x:
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

<!-- Banner -->
<div id="my_banner" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img id="banner_chibi" src="cute_scholar.png">
  </div>
</div>
<!--Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-default">
  <a><span id = "top_header"><span id = "red">Step</span> by <span id = "blue">Step</span> Korean</span></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <!--<li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li> -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Browse
     </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Main Lesson Catalog</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Phonetics Study</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Vocab</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test Yourself</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!--<li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </li>-->
    </ul>
    <!--<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
   </form>-->
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Main Body Content -->

<div class="row" id="main_content">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card left_card">
      <div class="card-body">
        Placeholder text.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="card right_card">
      <div class="card-body">
        Placeholder text.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card right_card" id="card_1">
      <div class="card-body">
        Placeholder text.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is the visual problem that I am noticing, at the very right (the black is not a part of the website). (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxaGF.jpg)
[image: visual]
Thank you so much, I would really appreciate any input. Additionally, if anyone notices bad habits in my code, please tell me too.

Comment: if you use the `row` class without a `container` parent, use also `m-0` to reset margins ;) `class="row m-0"`

Comment: Aah thank you! Noted for the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Add class 'no-gutters' to the row div.

```
<div id="my_banner" class="row no-gutters">

<div class="row no-gutters" id="main_content">
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
  src: url("Montserrat-Regular.ttf");
}

#my_banner {
  background-image: url('banner.jpg');
  "
 padding-bottom: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#banner_chibi {
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar,
.dropdown-menu {
  background: #e5e5e5 !important;
  border: 0;
}

.navbar li a {
  color: #7e7e7e;
}

#top_header {
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#red {
  color: #cd2d3a;
}

#blue {
  color: #0047a0;
}

#main_content {
  margin-top: 4%;
}

.left_card {
  width: 20%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 4%;
  position: fixed;
}

.right_card {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

#card_1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 1000%;
  top: 20%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #5e5e5e;
  overflow-x:
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

<!-- Banner -->
<div id="my_banner" class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <img id="banner_chibi" src="cute_scholar.png">
  </div>
</div>
<!--Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-default">
  <a><span id = "top_header"><span id = "red">Step</span> by <span id = "blue">Step</span> Korean</span></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <!--<li class="nav-item active">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li> -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Browse
     </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Main Lesson Catalog</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Phonetics Study</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Vocab</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test Yourself</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!--<li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </li>-->
    </ul>
    <!--<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
   </form>-->
  </div>
</nav>

<!-- Main Body Content -->

<div class="row no-gutters" id="main_content">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card left_card">
      <div class="card-body">
        Placeholder text.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="card right_card">
      <div class="card-body">
        Placeholder text.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card right_card" id="card_1">
      <div class="card-body">
        Placeholder text.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It worked! I am so excited. If possible, could you please tell me why that worked for future reference? But thank you very much!

Comment: class 'no-gutters' actually set the margin-left and margin-right to 0 plus padding-left and padding-right to 0 for the child col, col-*. You may refer to the bootstrap css.

Comment: Oooh that makes sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

See, I think this is due to the default margin of the HTML page.

In your CSS file, try this. It might help

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin : 0;
}
```

in your CSS use this (i removed `"` from the code)

```
#my_banner {
       background-image: url('banner.jpg');
       padding-bottom: 100px;
       overflow: hidden;
       width: 100%;
       max-width: 100%;
}
```

Share me your response after trying this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this was not the solution, but thank you for trying! When I have made suggested edits, this was the outcome. https://imgur.com/a/Inm5EAn
Yinsweet's solution of adding no-gutters to the classes solved the problem, and now I am trying learn from the experience.